# Get table field based on result of dropdown menu (poplated from another table field)

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, forms

I hope my title makes sense.
Basically, I have a MySQL table that has a few fields.  Importantly, one field called "species" is populated into a drop down box.  This drop down box lives in a HTML form, with the data coming from PHP.  What I am trying to do is have another field from the same table populate the HTML form field below species, and this other field is called "sku".  I am new to AJAX, and I think I understand how my script is supposed to work, but it's not returning any results.  Here is my main PHP script:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" media="screen" />
  <title>Add Inventory</title>
  <script>
function showUser(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getsku.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
 </head>
 <body>
<?php
session_start();

require_once('includes/config.inc.php');
require_once('includes/functions.inc.php');

$thisPage='add';
include('includes/navbar.inc.php');
?>

<h1>Add New Inventory Record</h1>
<form method="POST" action="submitadd.php" />

<table id="add">

<tr>
<td class="headings"><b>Species:</b></td>
<td><select name="species:" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
      <option value="select">Choose a Species</option>
      <?php
      $prodquery="SELECT name FROM products ORDER BY name ASC";
      $result=mysqli_query($con,$prodquery) or die(mysqli_error($con));
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<option value='" . $row['name'] . "'>" . $row['name'] . "</option>";
      }
      ?>
    </select>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="headings"><b>SKU:</b></td>
<td><input type="text" name="sku" value="<div id="txtHint" />" readonly="readonly" size="35" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="button1" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is getsku.php:

```
<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

require_once('includes/config.inc.php');

$sql="SELECT sku FROM products WHERE name = '".$q."'";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['sku'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

When I select an item in the drop down, I can see that something is happening but the expected result (the 'sku' of that product) is not appearing.

Can anyone help me out please?

Comment: Are you using Firefox? Install Firebug. It makes these kind of problems much easier to identify.

Comment: Using Firebug with Firefox, I can see that the AJAX script is working, but it's calling the "name" incorrectly.

Example, the Species name is (Aulonocara rubescens "Ruby Red") but the $_GET that is being called is:
<domain>/getsku.php?q=Aulonocara%20rubescens%20%22Ruby%20Red%22

With getsku.php getting that variable for q= by using $_GET, I am assuming it's getting:
Aulonocara%20rubescens%20%22Ruby%20Red%22

Instead of:
Aulonocara rubescens "Ruby Red"

So everything is working, but because the incorrect name, the SQL query is just returning no results.

Comment: Wait, I'm wrong.  While the URL is wrong, Firebug is showing me this:

Params:
q   Aulonocara rubescens "Ruby Red"

So it's seeing the variable correctly.  So something must be wrong with getsku.php?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up using for getsku.php that fixed my problem:

```
<?php
$q = html_entity_decode($_GET['q']);

require_once('includes/config.inc.php');

$sql="SELECT sku FROM products WHERE name = '".$q."'";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<td><input type='hidden' name='sku' value='" . $row['sku'] . "' readonly='readonly' size='35' /></td>";
  }

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```